# why is curl to https not working

Tags: https, curl

I can do the following without any problems:

```
curl -u "username:password" http://www.example.com/exportfile.xml
```

But if I try to use the same command to the https version of our site it fails

```
curl -u "username:password" https://www.example.com/exportfile.xml
```

This is what the error message looks like:

```
About to connect() to www.example.com port 443 (#0)
Trying "some ip"... connected
Connected to www.example.com (some ip) port 443 (#0)
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
NSS error -5938
Closing connection #0
SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

All help is appreciated

Comment: How Does Curl Fail? What Error Messages are produced?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no we are not behind a proxy

Comment: Make sure your system is up to date.

Comment: Ensure the site supports TLS v1.0.  Most installations of curl do not support TLSv1.1 or later yet.  Test the site with [Qualys SSL Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html)

Comment: @ITFun have you tested my answer? Yay/nay feedback would be appreciated as to whether it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `-k/--insecure` parameter.

From man page:

> (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to  perform  "insecure"  SSL  connections  and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless `-k, --insecure` is used.

```
$ curl -sku "username:password" "https://www.example.com/exportfile.xml"
```

I always prefer to use the `-s/--silent` parameter as well, unless I am downloading something and want to see the stats.

Also note that using the `-s` parameter does not prevent verbose output when using the `-v` parameter.